# Cruisecontrol.net 1.6 - CCNet Status becoming "Unknown"

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

I'm having some problem with my scheduled build. This is how it goes:

1. Created the project entry in my cruisecontrol.net config file. At this time, CC dashboard will show the new project entry, with CCNet status "Unknown". This project will have  a scheduledTrigger, so that it runs daily at a specific time.
2. I trigger a build for the project and the Build is Successful. Now the CCNet status is "Running".
3. The daily builds happen in a consistent manner for some days. The CCNet status still shows "Running" every day.
4. At some point  (after few days), the CCNet status of this project suddenly changes to "Unknown", after which the scheduled build doesn't happen.

In short, CC scheduled build happens only when the CCNet status is "Running". Once it changes to "Unknown", the scheduled build stops triggering.

In my case, the CCNet status is getting changed from "Running" to "Unknown" without any specific reason, and hence the scheduled build stops.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the cruise control .net service, whether its running or may be it stops. Check whether build log files are there..

Answer (score 8):

$ccnetINSTALLDIR\server\ProjectsState.xml.

Remove any entries of projects in the  node in the ProjectState.xml file. This will fix the issue. Restart ccnet server if needed

Answer (score 1):

One possibile cause for this is that state file is getting deleted. State file location is defined by state tag in the ccnet.

You can check if any clean up process is turning ccnet service off and deleting the state files.

Comment: In my case deleting the state file (in the CCNet/server directory), forcing a build and then restoring the build number fixed things.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.
Try shortening the name of the project name or just rename for project in file ccnet.config.
I have shortened the project name, then restarted CCNet service and CCNet status immediately went to "Running".
My scheduled tasks ran without issue after that.

Comment: Would probably work if you made it longer as well, as long as it does not match the project name in ProjectState.xml.